# How to save DOM references of elements whose parent innerHTML property was set to empty string (in IE)

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, clone, innerhtml

In IE, when one sets the `innerHTML` property of a DOM element, this automatically empties the `innerHTML` property all the child references. How can I keep the child in memory in order to be able to clone it later and append it to the parent?

Example HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
var parent = document.querySelector('#parent', document);
var child = document.querySelector('#child', parent);

parent.innerHTML = '';
// at this point child.innerHTML is ALSO empty!!!
// I want to clone later the child back into the parent
```

How can I keep the child in memory? Is `child.outerHTML` the only solution?

PS: in IE (up to 10), no jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple problem of references versus values.

The JS `var child = X` returns a *reference* to the DOM - not the graph of associated values.

To hold the value of the child graph before it gets wiped out by the innerHTML setting, it needs to be copied first, including deep-cloning the children if desired.

There is an example of resolving the broken IE DOM element cloning here:
http://brooknovak.wordpress.com/2009/08/23/ies-clonenode-doesnt-actually-clone/

Comment: Just looks like a simple problem but: 1. `cloneNode(source)` is not a valid syntax and 2. it does not work with deep cloning in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var parent = document.querySelector('#parent', document),
    child = document.querySelector('#child', document);
parent.removeChild(child);
// Later you can return child to document:
parent.appendChild(child);
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4sbA/).